# Unable to assign a default value using Generics in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

I have this piece of code in Typescript.

```
export class CommonResponse<T extends EmptyOutputBody> {
    output: T  = new EmptyOutputBody();
    successful: boolean = false;
    responseCode: number = 200;
}

export class EmptyOutputBody {
    alerts: string[] = [];
}
```

I wanted to assign a default value to the generic typed property `output`. Generic type `T` extends `EmptyOutputBody` and I thought that assigning an object of Parent class (`EmptyOutputBody`) of Generic type `T` would work for me. But this code gives me error on `output` property. 
it says

> Type 'EmptyOutputBody' is not assignable to type 'T'.
>    'EmptyOutputBody' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'EmptyOutputBody'

Can someone help me how can I instantiate a generic type in this case, or how can I provide initial value to `output` which should be of type `T` or `EmptyOutputBody`.

Answer (score 0):

For the initial assignment, while declaring, you can use as syntax as below given example.

There is a huge discussion around that you can read more here.

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36821

```
export class CommonResponse<T extends EmptyOutputBody> {
  output: T = new EmptyOutputBody() as T; // Modify here
  successful: boolean = false;
  responseCode: number = 200;
}

export class EmptyOutputBody {
  alerts: string[] = [];
}
const res = new CommonResponse()
res.output = new EmptyOutputBody() // NO issue
```

Comment: Here, we are explicitly converting its Type to T. Is there no other way do assign the default value of type T?